# On-prem Office Online Server don't show users markers when users co-working with documents

Tags: 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, office-web-apps, co-authoring

We have SharePoint 2016 Farm (`build version 16.0.4417.1002`) and Office Online Server (`build version 16.0.6814.2226`).

Our issue is that `Office Online Server` doesn't show users markers when multiple users are editing same Word/PowerPoint/Excel documents in the browsers.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design; or rather a feature which on-prem OOS lacks. There's nothing to fix here.

Comment: You mean what this feature works only in cloud version (SharePoint Online/Office 365)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with SharePoint 2016 On Premise and Office Online Server 2016.

The problem was in the OOS configuration, to get the Co-Authoring feature, you must configurate the AllowHTTP property to equal True.

"Set-OfficeWebAppsFarm -AllowHTTP".

Once the property was set up, the Co-Authoring flag start working on Word online, Excel online and PowerPoint Online.

Regards.

Comment: We can't use HTTP because of the requirements of our it security officiers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. But I need to use HTTPS on OOS. if I change OOS to HTTP, It will show cursors of co-working users.